# C#: Moq System.NotSupportedException : Can not apply commission concerns to component because it appears to be a target-less proxy

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, moq

I am trying to mock a service, and receiving the following error below in unit test. How can this be resolved? What does this error mean? Is it something maybe with await/async?

```
services.AddSingleton(a =>
{
    var mock = new Mock<IUserResolverService>();
    mock.Setup(b => b.GetUser()).Returns(5);
    return mock.Object;
});
```

> System.NotSupportedException : Can not apply commission concerns to component Common.Services.IUserResolverService_175a16cd-d798-4fbd-b343-1ba0eb5e0ad6 because it appears to be a target-less proxy. Currently those are not supported. DefaultKernel.ResolveComponent(IHandler handler, Type service, IDictionary additionalArguments, IReleasePolicy policy) IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy) ScopedWindsorServiceProvider.GetServiceInternal(Type serviceType, Boolean isOptional) line 55

**More Code Data:**

```
    private async Task<IServiceProvider> GetProvider()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();
        services.AddSingleton(new Mock<ISharedServicesApiClient>().Object);
        services.AddSingleton(new Mock<IAddressValidator>().Object);
        services.AddSingleton(new Mock<IAddressValidationService>().Object);

        services.RegisterMappingProfiles(
            new PropertyManagementDataMappingProfile(),
            new ApplicationServicesMappingProfile()
        );
        services.AddSingleton(a =>
        {
            var mock = new Mock<IUserResolverService>();
            mock.Setup(b => b.GetUser()).Returns(5);
            return mock.Object;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<PropertyContext>(
            a => a.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb").UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll),
            ServiceLifetime.Singleton);

        services.AddDbContext<AuditablePropertyContext>(
            a => a.UseInMemoryDatabase("TestDb").UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll),
            ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
        services.AddSingleton<DbContext, AuditablePropertyContext>();

        services.AddSingleton<DbContext, PropertyContext>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAddressAppService, AddressAppService>();
        services.AddSingleton<IAddressRepository, AddressRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IPartyContactRepository, PartyContactRepository>();
        services.AddSingleton<IPartyMailingAddressRepository, PartyMailingAddressRepository>();

        var provider = services.GetServiceProvider();
        var db = provider.GetRequiredService<PropertyContext>();
        await db.AddTestData();
        return provider;
    }

    [Fact]
    public async Task AddNewAddressAlternateAddTest()
    {
        var provider = await GetProvider();
        var manager = provider.GetRequiredService<IAddressAppService>();
        var request =
            SitusAndPartyAddressDataSeed.GetSingleApnRequestForAdd(AddressType.Alternate);
        var result = await manager.UpdatePartyAndSitusAddresses(request);
        // new AddressId is 3
        Assert.True(result.Body == NewAddressId);
```

Comment: Just a hunch, but what happens if you arrange the mock for IUserResolverService and pass the defined object into AddSingleton() instead of defining it from within?

Comment: hi @AdamG you are correct, please write in answer and I can send points !! By the way, hunch? I took 2 hours on this, and you are guessing instinctively :) ?? pretty good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on the "hunch" with some reasoning, you're setting up a singleton for a mocked instance of IUserResolverService, but as written you're uniquely composing and returning that mocked object using a delegate rather than just creating a single instance of the completed mock and registering it instead like you are with all the other ones. Given the blend of synchronous and asynchronous operations, it looks like your test is causing Moq to struggle with the lifecycle/creation of the object.

If we change this:

```
services.AddSingleton(a =>
{
     var mock = new Mock<IUserResolverService>();
     mock.Setup(b => b.GetUser()).Returns(5);
     return mock.Object;
 });
```

To this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IResolverService();
mock.Setup(b => b.GetUser()).Returns(5);
services.AddSingleton(mock.Object);
```

You're then passing in the actual single instance of the mock instead, which might resolve whatever is causing the issue, be it the lifecycle or late binding (or something else, but hey).